# Missing outputs in Stencil's Angular build target

Tags: angular, typescript, stenciljs

I am trying to setup a project using StencilJS, Angular and the corresponding Stencil build target for Angular. However, the generated code does not include the event outputs I define in the web components. Thus, type errors are thrown in my Angular project.

I am using the default Angular output target. Is there any obvious thing I am missing? I can see that the EventEmitter is triggered correctly inside the web component.

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  tag: 'dummy-component'
})
export class DummyComponent {

  @Event() onFocus!: EventEmitter<FocusEvent>;

  // ...
}
```

**Stencil Config:**

```
export const config: Config = {
  // ...
  outputTargets: [
    angularOutputTarget({
      componentCorePackage: '@dummy/test',
      directivesProxyFile: '../angular/projects/test/src/lib/directives/proxies.ts'
    }),
    // ...
  ]
}
```

I can see that in the generated `proxies.ts`, there are only inputs defined, no outputs.

Comment: Same here! Proxies.ts file won't include outputs array, just inputs. See this issue from project's github. Seems that pr is not working anymore? https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-ds-output-targets/issues/54